# 403 Error when using save buttons

Tags: wp-admin, apache

I just installed Wordpress on my home server. Everything was working fine until a hit a save button in a plugin and got a 403 error saying I didn’t have access to ap-admin/options.php. Strangely enough, if I load that page independently of the save it loads just fine. I found also it has issues when clicking the same button in the permalink page.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is it a security feature of my Apache server that I need to turn off?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your plugin. It might not be compatible with the WordPress version that you are using. Would you please tell me its name and your WordPress version number?

Comment: I am using seedprod for a coming soon page. I am using the latest version of Wordpress as of yesterday. I believe it’s 5.0.1. Seed prod version is also the latest, at 5.0.23

Comment: OK. In that case, you should contact the developer of the plugin. I believe that your problem has been originated from it.